# Python 3.x replace for loop with something faster

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, time, lambda, python-itertools

I am trying to produce a vector that represents the match of a string and a list's elements. I have made a function in python3.x:

```
def vector_build (docs, var):
    vector = []
    features = docs.split(' ')
    for ngram in var:            
        if ngram in features:
            vector.append(docs.count(ngram))
        else:
            vector.append(0)
    return vector
```

It works fine:

```
vector_build ('hi my name is peter',['hi', 'name', 'are', 'is'])
```

> Out: [1, 1, 0, 1]

But this function is not scalable to significant data. When its string parameter 'docs' is heavier than 190kb it takes more time that need. So I am trying to replace the for loop with map function like:

```
var = ['hi', 'name', 'are', 'is']
doc = 'hi my name is peter'
features = doc.split(' ')
vector = list(map(var,if ngram in var in features: vector.append(doc.count(ngram))))
```

But this return this error:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Is there a way to replace that for loop with map, lambda, itertools in order to make the execution faster?

Comment: I think you need to take a look at the documentation for `map`. This isn't how you would execute it. The first argument is the function you want to use and the remaining arguments are the inputs for the function in the first argument of `map`. Plus I don't think you'd gain much going this route.

Comment: Thank you, do you suggest a more effective library or function to speed up this process?

Comment: Numpy might be faster--it generally is. Specifically look at `numpy.isin`.

Comment: I can't use numpy because it will later run on a .NET instance which has problems reading numpy for python3.

Comment: `map` and list-comprehensions are not appreciably faster than an equivalent for-loop.

Comment: The problem isn't your for-loop, is that you are not using the right data-structures. You are doing a membership test on the result of `features = docs.split(' ')`, which will be a list. List membership tests are O(N), that is, the time it takes scales linearly with the number of members in the list. Instead, use a `set`, which has *constant time* membership testing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension for this task. Also, lookups in a set of features should help the function some as well.

```
var = ['hi', 'name', 'are', 'is']
doc = 'hi my name is peter'
features = doc.split(' ')
features_set = set(features) #faster lookups
vector = [doc.count(ngram) if ngram in features_set else 0 for ngram in var] 
print(vector)
```

Comment: It gives me this error pointing to 'for': SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @anitasp i tried running it on my machine, and noticed that the variable "doc" was wrongly spelt in my unedited version. However, the code itself seems fine, i do not get the error you are getting. what python version are you on?

Comment: List comprehensions are not appreciably faster than an equivalent for-loop

Comment: Didn't notice you had used a set. You should highlight that aspect, because that is the *important* aspect of your answer. I would personally just keep the for-loop.